# angular 6 directive for accepting only 1 number before decimal eg 2.12548

Tags: angular

I have a situation where a user enters a value that is <=9. I need a directive which will,

**1)** Only accept a number

**2)** Only 1 digit before the decimal point

**3)** And 6 digits after the decimal point

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @youri trying various regular expression   this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/^(?:\d{0,1}\.?(\d)|\d{0,6})?$/, '');
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }